# How to removeObserver in Swift 5 using addObserver closure method

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, swift5, nsnotificationcenter

This is my first post.
I'm Japanese iOS engineer (just became this month).

I have a trouble with `removeObserver` method of `NotificationCenter` in Swift 5.

I added observer to ViewController (VC) by using closure type `addObserver`.
I want to remove this Observer when VC's deinitialization has called.

I wrote `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` in VC's `deinit` method. But, this seemed not to work for me.

What's the problem???

Additionally, if my code has memory leak problem, let me know how to fix it.

Here's piece of my code.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in

            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.loadWeather(notification.object)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print(#function)
        print("ViewController died")

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it means, _But, this seemed not to work for me._ ? You mean **deinit** not getting called when you left from it?

Comment: @Sateesh Sorry for poor English. That means, "`NotificationCenter` doesn't seem to be removed even I called `removeObserver` in `deinit`".

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "`NotificationCenter` doesn't seem to be removed"? Do you expect `NotificationCenter` to get deallocated too? 2) is your `print("ViewController died")` line hit? I mean do you see it logged in the console?

Comment: @Honey 1) I want to check if I'm really removing Observer. 2) Yes. I confirmed "ViewController died" in console.

Comment: Did you get a chance to take a look into my answer? The accepted answer is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your observer object to current view controller.

From [apple doc.s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver), object is

> The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is,
>   only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                                       object: self,
                                       queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.loadWeather(notification.object)
}
```

Removing observer from `NotificationCenter`

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

**ANOTHER WAY**

You can also make copy of Notification Observer object and remove it from `NotificationCenter` in `deinit`.

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
var loadWeatherObserver: NSObjectProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadWeatherObserver = notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                                                         object: nil,
                                                         queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.loadWeather(notification.object)
    }
}

deinit {
    if (loadWeatherObserver != nil) {
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(loadWeatherObserver!)
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you removing the observer in your first example?

Comment: In the question, @Daichi Hayashi has written code for removing observer in **deinit**

Comment: I see, but the answer as itself is a bit unclear. Can you make an edit?

Comment: @Sateesh Thank you for your great answer. First answer was not working because the notification is `.didBecomeActiveNotification`. Your `ANOTHER WAY` seems to be working.

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining why this answer is a bit misleading, specifically the first solution.

Answer (score 17):

## [Closure-based addObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver)

> If you use the **closure-based** variant of addObserver, the **token** (not `self`) is
> the observer. The notification center has no knowledge at all about
> `self` in this situation. The documentation is not super clear on
> this.
>
> <sub>[from Twitter](https://twitter.com/olebegemann/status/1253006445295042565?s=20)</sub>

Meaning it's meaningless to do: `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)`

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver) recommend two ways:

### Normal way

Subscribe as you normally do:

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
self.localeChangeObserver = center.addObserverForName(NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { (note) in
    print("The user's locale changed to: \(NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier)")
}
```

Remove the observer at some point of code.
`NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.localeChangeObserver)` e.g. through a function or in `deinit`

Note: You'd still need to use `[weak self]` to avoid retain cycles.

> To avoid a retain cycle, use a weak reference to `self` inside the block when `self` contains the observer as a strong reference.

### Single subscribe

Remove the observer immediately after the first time it gets a callback

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
var token: NSObjectProtocol?
token = center.addObserverForName("OneTimeNotification", object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { (note) in
    print("Received the notification!")
    center.removeObserver(token!)
}
```

---

## [Selector-based addObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver)

If you use the selector-based add, **`self`** (there is no token) the observer. Having that said, you should **avoid** doing:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

because your code may not be the only code adding observers that involve the object. When removing an observer, remove it with the most specific detail possible. For example, if you used a name and object to register the observer, use `removeObserver(_:name:object:)` with the name and object.

It’s only safe to call `removeObserver(something)` in the `deinit` method, other than that don’t use it use `removeObserver(_:name:object:)` instead.

Calling `removeObserver(self)` is incorrect outside `deinit`, because you’d be removing all observations set for the object. Calling it inside `deinit` isn’t incorrect, but meaningless, because the object is to be deallocated immediately.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In the first method of the accepted answer, observer is not added to `self`. So, removing like that in `deinit` does not have effect.

Comment: Adding a thing: if you're targeting iOS 9.0 +, you don't need to manually remove the observer if you added with selector. iOS does it for you.