# Strange Undetectable memory leak

Tags: ios, xcode

I manually created a memory leak, but the Debug Memory Graph cannot detect it.
This only happens on the controller, not on the general object type.
Any one konw why?
[image]

This is the code I used

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        present(Demo(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
class Demo : UIViewController {
    var obj:Demo?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        obj = self
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly a dup, but very much: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831009/what-is-the-difference-between-leaks-and-allocations-living-in-instrumen/56265569#56265569. Tldr: There are **3** types of memory issues. Leaks, abandoned memories and cached memory. The memory debugger will ONLY show a _purple_ indicator for leaks. Basically anytime it sees two strong references pointing back to one another it will know it will cause it a leak. (1/2)

Comment: However for **abandoned memory** e.g. notificationCenter issue you have, 2 objects are not strongly pointing to one another. It's just a _root path_ (Notification Center) which remains in memory all the time is pointing to an object and never letting go. For such memory issues, you won't see the purple indicator. Yet by going through the flow a few times, you'd see an increased _number_ of unreleased instances of the related classes. ie if you repeat the flow you'd see `(2)` instead of `(1)` for the number of classes you have.Because each time it strongly referenced by notificationCenter (2/2)

Comment: @Honey unfortunatly it's not a case of **abandoned memory** because when we call addObserver the **NSNotificationCenter** creates **__NSObserver** wrapper that have weak reference to our class instance.

Comment: If it hold's Demo View Controller with strong reference the elimination of  **obj = self** wouldn't fix the   leak. But we see that it helps.

Comment: it seems that `NSNotificationCenter` covered this `Demo` object leak.

Comment: @Mark it still strongly holds onto the _token_. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344541/how-to-removeobserver-in-swift-5-using-addobserver-closure-method/61395815#61395815). Also for the Block based, you still have to be considerate of using `weak` yourself, as the observer keeps sending messages...

Comment: @Honey We discuss selector based case, not closure one. For selector based method addObserver from apple documentation: "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you do not need to unregister an observer that you created with this function. If you forget or are unable to remove an observer, the system cleans up the next time it would have posted to it."
If a selector based observer would create token that hold a strong reference, the deinit method of our object wouldn't be called, in normal case where isn't any another memory leaks. It's a Proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like that UIViewController begin observation of UIApplicationSuspendedNotification.

There is 2 method to begin of observations:

1. [addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver)
2. [addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver)
   Both keep weak reference to our Demo view controller.
   Demo vc is addObserver through first method. It's seems that apple didn't consider as memory leaks object's that observing **NotificationCenter**.

I get this information through follow debugging steps:

1.
After opening debugger with enabled with enabled **Malloc Stack Logging** in project scheme i find out **__NSObservers** references.
[image]

2.
Then i look at Backtrace and find out that there is a calls to **[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]**.
[image]

3. Im added sybmolic breakpoint with method name **[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]** and printed all argument $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5 $arg6 and find the name of observation.
4. Using the address of NotificationCenter and and adress of my ViewController, i'm deleted the observation through [ NotificationCenterAdress removeObserver:ViewControllerAdress] and reopened memory debugger. And debugger treats viewController as memory leak. (there is 12 instances on screenshot because i taped on background multiple times).
   [image]

Comment: yes，`NotificationCenter` did `cover` leaked objects.

Comment: is this a apple's bug?

Comment: @chdo Yes it looks like bug in memory debug graph.